# Error on booting on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, acpi

My Ubuntu 22.04 works fine but throws these errors when booting.

```
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
snapd-desktop-i[2278]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f7bf22723d4 sp 00007ffdb0e022c8 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f7bf2248000+9a000]
```

What does this mean?

Comment: It is common to get some error/warning messages also when Ubuntu works correctly afterwards. I think you need not worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Sudodus,
 now I sleep more peacefully

Comment: The ACPI errors may be ignored, but not the snapd error. A segfault is an error that should not happen.